# Filemaker Database design for Film project

Tags: database, image, filemaker, table-relationships

I have been asked to create a database to track the frames in a short industrial video.

I have 10,000 frames which are each referenced in a container field in Table "Thumbnails" with an associated frame number (a positive 6-digit integer).

I have another Table, "Shots" which contains: Shots (text, a shot name), Shot order (a decimal number), Frame IN (an integer number), Frame OUT (another integer), and duration (a calculated value from Frame In to Frame out)...

I want to be able to call up the thumbnails in a container, so that if I call up shot 1001, i can see all the thumbnail frames from table 2, which apply to the shot in question, using the frame numbers in the Thumbnails table, and the Frame IN/OUT/Duration in the "Shots" table records...

Thing is, I have never tried to join table together or pull from 2 tables to get a result. I know this is a big question, but I was hoping someone might be able to point me in a direction to start, using Filemaker Pro 11.

Currently, the frame numbers get imported with the frame file, which is defined by the image filename. So I have to use those numbers when looking for frames in the "Thumbnail" table.

Any thoughts at all would be a huge help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a relationship between the two tables as:

```
Shots::FrameIn ≤ Thumbnails::FrameNumber
AND
Shots::FrameOut ≥ Thumbnails::FrameNumber
```

you will be able to view all shot's frames in a *portal* to Thumbnails, placed on a layout of Shots.

Comment: OK I will try that. I have heard of Portals, but haven't tried to use one yet. I guess that would work going forward If I have a change in the frame in and out or duration of a shot, even after the change? (Like if I had to update the thumbnails of the frames and then see the difference in the shots layout? Do i need to create key fields between the two tables? I.E. frame in linked to thumbnail record frame number? Do you mind if i ask.. .how do I link records when importing (of referencing external files) in the thumbnails table?

Comment: I suggest you try it first. I believe it will answer most, if not all your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It worked like a charm, once i figured out how to apply the filter to the portal and sort the results that are displayed. Thanks very much!!

Comment: I am not sure why you need to "apply the filter to the portal". The relationship should provide all the filtering you need, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Ah yes - I am filtering the results because I want to be able to adjust which thumbnail images I can see in the portal - Head and Tail images, or set it up to show the thumb images sequentially - like it is playing video (slooowly). I set a global field to hold the current frame, used a filter to look for just that frame...then loop until it hits the last frame... runs only about 1 frame a second though. Thanks again. Jamie